# Calculating the peak power of a signal on python

Tags: discrete-signals, python, signal-power

As far as I've researched, the energy and power of a given (discrete) signal are given by

$$E = \sum_n \left|x_n \right|^2$$

$$P = \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{2N+1}\sum_n \left|x_n \right|^2$$

Where N is the lenght of the given signal.

Im working with a signal embedded in some non-gaussian noise, and I want to calculate the ratio of the peak power of the signal and the power of the noise (see label of Fig 2 on https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.00008.pdf).

Now, the power of the signal I already know how to compute, but I have not been able to find a precise definition of what peak power is, and I have not found a library on python to help me on that.

Is there a library on python that does this, or is there a concrete definition of peak power I can use to calculate it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Peak power is simply the highest square of any of the samples you encounter.

Average power is simply the average square.